# Equation to calculate flow rate

Tags: fluid-mechanics, valves, air

Assume you have a solid walled sphere with an opening of diameter x. The sphere has volume  0.02 litres and has air at 1.4 bars.

What general equation would be appropriate to correctly size the diameter of the sphere's opening such that pressurized air in sphere would be released in exactly 40 seconds? End pressure should be 1 bar

Comment: The sphere is solid... or do you mean solid wall?

Comment: Yes Mike. I meant a solid walled sphere. Which equation would be appropriate?

Comment: What have you considered so far? And that must be gauge pressure then.

Comment: Ambient pressure, velocity of air from the sphere. And volumetric flow rate.

Comment: "Gauge pressure" = pressure above ambient.  "Absolute pressure" = pressure above vacuum.

Comment: And note that "ambient pressure" is a bit of a trap, too -- if you do the experiment at sea level on Europa your results will be different (for the same sphere) than if you do the experiment at sea level on Earth.

Comment: And -- "pressurized air would be released in..." won't work, because even though for most of the time the flow will be proportional to the square root of pressure, at some point the flow will go laminar and it'll be proportional to pressure (if I'm getting my fluid dynamics right).  At that point the pressure differential will be a decaying exponential, which will, in theory, never settle to zero.  So you need to define whatever ending (gauge) pressure means "close enough to zero" for the purposes of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the explanation. Let's say the initial pressure is 1.4 bars and ending pressure is 1 bar.

Comment: @TimWescott note gauge pressure can be below ambient as well...

Comment: A google search gives this which might help: https://www.engineersedge.com/fluid_flow/discharge-air-orifice.htm

Comment: It is not possible to achieve unless you have some very exacting outside parameters. If you do not then each time you try to do this it will be a different time period. Factors of influence are Internal temperature, external temperature. External pressure (you have given Internal).     water content of the air in the sphere and relative humidity outside the sphere. height above sea level. Obviously the opening must have some sort of open and close mechanism so the action of his will be critical. When you have this under control as Tim alluded to the release of pressure will not be linear